# How do I create a VBA Pop Up message based on file name?

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a spreadsheet template that I would like the user to save immediately with a new name.  I have VBA code that creates the new name and puts it in the save as dialogue box.

I would like to have a pop up that tells the user to 'Save As' the file as soon as the file is opened.  I would like it to only show up if the template is opened and not after it is saved with a new name.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
MsgBox "You MUST use 'Save As' to save this file with a new name before editing"
End Sub
```

Once the file has been saved with a different name I don't want the Pop up to show up.  I was thinking that the sub could read the name of the file and if it matches the predefined template name "Field Time Template.xlxm".

This may be a new question but it would also be nice to have a script that let prevented or notified user if they hit 'Save' instead of 'Save As'

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, when you use the Save As feature, the workbook's name is changed, right? You could just involve the MsgBox with `If ThisWorkbook.Name = #TemplateName Then `

Comment: @Lodi solution should do the trick but what happens if the user simply cancels the `Save As` dialog box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think about opening a save as prompt upon opening of your template after checking the name of your activeworkbook. Upon canceling or overwriting your template, the workbook would close.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

NewName = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 27).Value
If ThisWorkbook.Name = "Field Time Template.xlsm" Then      
    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show(NewName) Then
        If ThisWorkbook.Name = "Field Time Template.xlsm" Then ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

This way I guess your second question would no longer matter.

Comment: That works really well @JvdV.  I had set up a formula to calculate the name and the following code to use for the Save As filename but since this does not actually open the file before the Save As function, this code will not work. Is there any way to incorporate it?    `Sub SaveAsAF1()
ThisFile = Range("AF1").Value
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisFile
End Sub`

Comment: Well, why would you want to do that? If you know what the filename should be before you open the saveas promt....why not save it with that name upon opening the template? That way you wont have to deal with saving by other users at all. Either way, I updated the answer.

Comment: I had never even thought of that as an option @JvdV, to automatically save it with the new name.  In running the new edit I get a compile error (syntax error) on the line `If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show Sheets(1), Cells(1,27).value Then`.  When I paste the code, this line also shows in red.

Comment: Sorry, made a silly mistake. It should be working now?

Comment: That worked well but there are some calculations that depend on the content of the filename.  Once I save the file with a different name I have to recalc the sheet.  Would it be possible to add something that would recalc the sheet after the Save As has completed? I would also be fine just having it save the sheet with the new name as you suggested.  Sorry to drag this out @JvdV.  You are very kind to help out like this.